# Topic Modeling and Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA)

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

I have written a LDA python program. In the last step:

```
for index, score in sorted(lda_model[bow_corpus], key=lambda tup: -1*tup[1]):
    output={}
    output['score'] = score
    output['index'] = index
    output_list.append(output)
print(output_list)
```

`[bow_corpus]` is the dictionary. The excel file has 125629 rows. If it's `[bow_corpus[125629]]`, it means i'm processing the 125629 rows in my excel file.

This gives me error

> 'list index out of range'

I want to write a for loop to process row 0 to row 125629, and export the results to a new excel file. How should I code this please? Thanks.

Comment: Is your count zero based?

Comment: Yes. It's zero based.

Comment: Then N-1 is the index of the last (Nth) row, N is already out-of-range.